# jQuery easing - causing form to not tab?

Tags: jquery, easing, jquery-easing

We are using the following plugin:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-swip/source/browse/trunk/jquery.easing.1.3.js?r=4

When it is in our site, we cannot tab between input boxes within forms - if we take this script out, we can?

We are using the latest release - http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Has anyone else came across this? How can it be fixed?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried tabindex on the fields?

Comment: Sure have, doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML header and some markup?